# How to insert a picture followed by text into an Excel file

Tags: vba, vbscript, excel, qtp

I need to insert pictures preceded and followed by text into an Excel file using VBscript (from QTP).

I cannot use ActiveCell.Worksheet.Pictures.Insert, because this command does not keep the picture inside the Excel file (since Excel 2007).

Method used:
`objExcel.ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddPicture ImagePath, False, True, 0, PrevHeight, ptWidth, ptHeight`

I need to find cell names above which my picture was inserted, or how to insert picture above certain cells instead of coordinates, or how to get a cell corresponding to a coordinate.

Found Shape's TopLeftCell and BottomRightCell properties, but cannot seem to make them return actual values in VBSCript.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the (from QTP) remark is throwing this off, but I just made a vbScript to do exactly what you wanted using Pictures Insert. My result was a nice fat picture lined up with upperleft corner at B2 and lower left corner at F16 - worth noting it was exactly at F16, but perhaps close enough! - with text above and below my picture. Also, when I closed the file and reopened the picture was still there.

```
Set objXL = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objXL.visible = true

Set wkb = objXL.Workbooks.Open("P:\Script\vbScript\Help\InsertPicture.xlsx")
Set ws = wkb.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set p = ws.Pictures.Insert("C:\Blue.jpg")

Set objRng = ws.Range("B2:F15")
With p
   .Top = objRng.Top
   .Left = objRng.Left
   .Width = objRng.Width 
   .Height = objRng.Height
End With

ws.Range("B1").Value = "myTop"
ws.Range("B16").Value = "myBottom"
```

Comment: The pictures can be of a different size. It should not be resized as well

Comment: in that case, just take the .width and the .height off the code. i would imagine, if you get crafty, after you set the top left position of the picture to a given cell, you can then measure the  height of the picture, and take those measurements against excel row heights (standard 15) and determine which cell is directly under the picture.

Comment: That's what I wanted to avoid - to calculate the cell height
Are you sure there is nothing else that can be done?

Comment: Well, I don't know if the workbooks you are inserting the pictures into have pre-existing formatting or anything, but Excel has a standard row height of 15, so it should be very easy to play with against the picture height... say with a RoundUp(picture_height/15)...  that answer will give you how many cells you need to offset to get the first full cell at the bottom of the picture